# Azure AD B2C -Identity Framework Experience Timeline

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am wondering if there has been any conversation about WHEN and IF the Identity Framework Experience might move from Preview to GA?   I can see it's been at least a year since it was placed in Preview.  I'm nervous about building a new solution on it, if it is not going to make it to GA.

Thanks!

Chad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussed with Azure Experts. A timeline is not yet known.